# Let the user answer an enigma to use the computer

Tags: services

I want to create a simple program starting when a user logs in on the computer. The user has to answer an enigma, otherwise he can't use the computer, the program is acting just like a parental control.

How can we prevent the computer from being used if the user can't answer the question ?

This is just a proof of concept so I'm interested in the answer for any common OS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of it to encrypt your drive and set a custom password prompt (the riddle) whose answer is the password. Ι have never used [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/), but according to [this page](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/fake-error-msg-boot-truecrypt/), the procedure is as  follows:

1. Install TrueCrypt
2. Encrypt your system drive (`C:` or `/` or what have you)
3. Set a custom message to be displayed in the pre-boot authentication screen. This will be the riddle. As long as you've set up your password to be the answer to the riddle, you will be able to log in by giving the right answer.